# If one div is equal in height to another div do something - on a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple divs that all output the same thing on a loop. So essentially I have 6 divs containing images on my page that have an on hover that displays a second image.

Unless `.first-image` and `.last-image` are equal in height I want the last image to be `display: none;`

Each of the 6 different divs contain images of all different heights so I need each one to be 'judged' individually. So on a loop I guess.

Ive put together this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pL9tnt2n/3/) to try and show what I'm trying to achieve but I've not quite got it how I want it. - When you hover on the 2nd & 3rd divs the on hover shouldn't be displaying.

```
$('.product-img-loop').each(function () {
   var firstImg = $('.first-image').height();
   var lastImg = $('.last-image');

   if (firstImg == lastImg.height()) {
     $('.last-image').css('display', 'block');
   } else {
     $('.last-image').css('display', 'none');
   }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is not working? I opened you fiddle, what is wrong? which is going away from your expectation? can you explain a little more?

Comment: Apparently it's OK, what is the issue? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pL9tnt2n/2/)

Comment: Sure so basically if the heights are not equal then the red box shouldn't be displaying, the last image should be display:none; at the moment its still showing. Also in my actual site I got it to do that but its doing the same thing to all and not looping through each individual one.

Comment: The second and third divs shouldn't be displaying an on hover but they are?

Comment: consider adding image instead of using red background `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is impossible to hide `.hidden` box because it has an `!important` overriding it:

```
    .reveal .hidden {
        display: block !important;
        visibility: visible !important;
    }
```

The red box will be displayed EVER because `!important` attribute removes all previous styles.
To solve it, just remove the important attribute and test it.

Another problem is that loop executes only on load the page, and when you hover the images don't execute it. Because of this, the achievement is very hard. Maybe if you try to explain better we can transform your code in something simplest.

## EDIT

As we talk in comments, here you are a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ak88Lh02/2/

```
    $('.image').on('mouseover', function() {
        var reveal = $(this).find('.reveal');
        var hide = $(this).find('.hide');

        if(reveal.height() == hide.height())  {
            hide.show()
        }
    }).on('mouseout', function() {
        var hide = $(this).find('.hide');
        hide.hide();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but removing the !important doesn't make any difference? The $(window).load point has helped though. Although I still can't get it to work.

Comment: The difference is that `display:block` without important you can override with `display:none`. Otherwise, you can't override with important

Comment: The problem i have is that if I don't have window.load the heights of the images are 0 for some reason and i can't figure out why?

Comment: In the snippet the size is 0 because the images don't load. In your code, maybe because you need to put an event listener when window loads completely `$(window).on('load')` do the trick

Comment: Ah I see ok, would that go inside or outside the .each function?

Comment: I've added an alert so I can see if the height is outputting correctly. Putting that `$(window).on('load...'` has meant that the correct height outputs. The problem is however its looping through and saying that all 6 are the same height when infact they are different. Basically doing the same thing for the first one for all 6. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: I think that you need to make it in another way. I can suggest that comparison mades when hover through the images, and not when document loads. i try to make an example and share you, if I have some piece of free time.

Comment: See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ak88Lh02/2/ . Note that second box has `reveal` and `hide` with different heights

Comment: Thanks for your example I'm having trouble replicating this in my site but I'll keep trying. Thanks for giving me something to go with.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's a solution that involves adding a new class that has a `:hover` effect associated and removing that hover effect from the common `reveal` class.

```js
$('.product-img-loop').each(function () {
    var firstImg = $('.first-image').height();
    var lastImg = $('.last-image').height();
    /*alert('First image height is: ' + firstImg + '; Second image height is: ' + lastImg);*/
    if (firstImg != lastImg) {
        /*alert('image heights are DIFFERENT');*/
        $('.last-image').css('display', 'none');
        $('.newreveal').removeClass('newreveal');
        
    } else {
        alert('image heights are EQUAL');
        $('.last-image').css('display', 'block');
        
    }
});
```

```css
.reveal .hidden {
    display: block !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
}
.product:hover .reveal img {
    opacity: 1;
}
.reveal {
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.reveal .hidden {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.reveal .hidden.one {
    height: 60px;
}
.reveal .hidden.two {
    height: 30px;
}
.reveal .hidden.three {
    height: 80px;
}
.reveal .hidden img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.reveal1:hover .hidden {
    opacity: 1;
}

.newreveal:hover .hidden {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-img-loop">
    <div class="reveal reveal1">
        <a href="#" class="grid__image">
             <img class="first-image" src="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: '2048x2048' }}" alt="" />
         </a>
        <div class="hidden one">
            <a href="#" class="grid__image">
                <img class="last-image" src="{{ product.images.last | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" alt="" />
             </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reveal newreveal">
        <a href="#" class="grid__image">
             <img class="first-image" src="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: '2048x2048' }}" alt="" />first
         </a>
        <div class="hidden two">
            <a href="#" class="grid__image">
                 <img class="last-image" src="{{ product.images.last | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" alt="" />second
             </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reveal newreveal">
        <a href="#" class="grid__image">
             <img class="first-image" src="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: '2048x2048' }}" alt="" />first
         </a>
        <div class="hidden three">
            <a href="#" class="grid__image">
                 <img class="last-image" src="{{ product.images.last | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" alt="" />second
             </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle with different heights](http://jsfiddle.net/pL9tnt2n/5/)

[Fiddle with equal heights](http://jsfiddle.net/pL9tnt2n/6/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer although I'm not sure this achieves what I'm after I looked at the fiddles but the last images that have different heights are still displaying?

Comment: You want the two last images to hide completely if the heights are different or only the hover effect not to happen? I understood the latter, and that's what my answer does